# Visual Studio 2015 Config Transformation option missing

Tags: visual-studio, config, transformation

I just installed Visual Studio Prof 2015 (Ver 14.0.2542501 update 3) on Windows Server 2012 R2. I also installed Configuration Transform Extension. I am domain admin, and have added developers group into the local admin group and remote access group.

When I open VS and right click on app config for a project, I can see the Add Config Transformation option; however when a developer remotes into the machine as (they are also admin), the right click menu does not have the Config Transformation option.

I'm unsure as to why this is happening, since both Environments are set to "General", so I'm guessing it's a permissions thing?

Config Transformation option missing

[image: Config Transformation option missing]

Config Transformation option available

[image: Config Transformation option available]

Comment: I was able to get it to work by installing the extension on the user profile of the Developer who was missing the "Add Config Transormation" option. For some reason, when you install the extension, it does not globally install, it only installs for the user you are logged on as, which is really strange, almost every program I've ever installed, you do it once, and it works for all users, same behavior for extensions, but not for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the configuration exists first (you probably already have Debug and Release).  If it doesn't, then add it in the Configuration Manager (ie. Test, Prod, ...).  Once you have the configuration in place, build the solution and click the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer.
[Solution Explorer Top Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF3li.png)

Expand the Web.Config and all the configuration transforms will be present that previously existed.  If you created a new configuration, then switch to that build.  Right click on the Web.config file and the option to add a configuration file for your current build will be present.

Comment: There is no reason why you should have to have a configuration set up to do a transform. I know there are other, better ways somehow